# Loading Data in Increments of Ten Items Per Result Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

I’m trying to build a request that will load 10 items at a time from the server for each request. For instance when a user clicks a button, redirecting them to the next page, I want the first 10 items to show first while the requests for the other items are being made in the background. How should I go about doing this? I have an idea of how it could work, on the server side by setting the max number returned and from a starting position on each request, but is this the right way of looking at it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that sounds like a good way to handle it. This is often called "Pagination" of data.

Have your API handle an offset for which "page" of data you want to receive and a count of the max number of items to return for that page (pagesize). Here is an example of how you could implement this for Forms.

A contract for your ViewModel to implement:

```
public interface ISupportIncrementalLoading
{
    int PageSize { get; set; }

    bool HasMoreItems { get; set; }

    bool IsLoading { get; }

    Task LoadMoreItemsAsync();
}
```

An example implementation in a ViewModel:

```
#region ISupportIncrementalLoading Implementation

public int PageSize { get; set; } = 10;

public bool HasMoreItems { get; set; }

public async Task LoadMoreItemsAsync()
{
    await LoadMoreItemsCommand.ExecuteAsyncTask();
}

//...

#endregion
```

Example LoadMoreItemsCommand:

```
LoadMoreItemsCommand = new Command(async () =>
{
    int fetchOffset = Requests.Count;
    int fetchMax = PageSize;

    // "Pagination" of your API request starting at the offset
    // and getting a maximum of the `fetchMax` or "page size"
    Results = await GetRequestsAsync(fetchOffset, fetchMax);
});
```

To support this automatically in a control like a `ListView` you can customize a renderer or "effect" to do this. Here is a pruned example:

```
// Custom ListViewRenderer, iOS example
public class IncrementalListViewRenderer : ListViewRenderer
{
    public IncrementalListViewRenderer()
    {
    }

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<ListView> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (Control != null)
        {
            // Need to customize the source but not lose existing functionality so 
            // we need a copy of it to use
            UITableViewSource defaultSource = Control.Source;            
            Control.Source = new IncrementalDataSource(Element as IncrementalListView, defaultSource);            
        }
    }

    class IncrementalDataSource : UITableViewSource
    {
        readonly UITableViewSource existingSource;
        readonly IncrementalListView listView;
        readonly ISupportIncrementalLoading incrementalLoading;

        int lastPosition;
        int preloadMargin = 5;

        public IncrementalDataSource(IncrementalListView listView, UITableViewSource existingSource)
        {
            this.listView = listView;
            this.existingSource = existingSource;

            incrementalLoading = listView.BindingContext as ISupportIncrementalLoading;

            lastPosition = 0;

            LoadMoreItems();
        }

        public override UITableViewCell GetCell(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {
            int position = indexPath.Row;
            var itemsSource = listView.ItemsSource as IList;

            if (itemsSource != null)
            {
                int preloadIndex = Math.Max(itemsSource.Count - preloadMargin, 0);

                if ((position > lastPosition || (position == itemsSource.Count - 1)) && (position >= preloadIndex))
                {
                    lastPosition = position;

                    if(!incrementalLoading.IsLoading && incrementalLoading.HasMoreItems)
                        LoadMoreItems();
                }
            }

            var cell = existingSource.GetCell(tableView, indexPath);
            cell.SelectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None;

            return cell;
        }

        public override void RowSelected(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {
            existingSource.RowSelected(tableView, indexPath);
        }

        public override nint RowsInSection(UITableView tableview, nint section)
        {
            return existingSource.RowsInSection(tableview, section);
        }

        void LoadMoreItems()
        {
            // Note the use of Nito.AsyncEx lib
            INotifyTaskCompletion taskCompletion = NotifyTaskCompletion.Create(LoadMoreItemsAsync());
        }

        public async Task LoadMoreItemsAsync()
        {
            await incrementalLoading.LoadMoreItemsAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

This leverages the techniques from [this](https://github.com/HBSequence/Sequence.Plugins/tree/master/InfiniteScrollPlugin) plugin.